# How to increment a variable inside an XSLT template?

Tags: xslt

here is briefly the problem I'm facing:

I have built a custom Content Query webpart, I fill this CQWP with items from a list. What I would like to do is to have a special separator each 3 items.

How to tell the XSLT that the current item is the 3, 6 or 9th one, and therefore, that a separator has to be put ?

what I have thought of would be to do something like that in the itemstyle.xsl:

```
<xsl:variable name="increment" select="0"/>
<xsl:template>
<xsl:with-variable name="increment" select="$increment+1"/>
<xsl:if increment = multiple de 3>
-put a separator-
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

but it appears that global variable cannot be used this way. Therefore my second idea would to get sortof the "row number" of the corresponding item in order to get the same information.

Does anybody have any idea of how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: The problem (besides the fact that in any functional language variables cannot be incremented), is that you haven't shown the source XML document neither the wanted result. In this case nothing can produce any result from any XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT does not do destructive update. Therefore you cannot assign a value to a variable and then overwrite the variable with a new value later.

In your case, you can use the position() function with modulus arithmetic:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
  <!-- normal processing here -->
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 0">
    <!-- separator here -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I've already tried it with no success: position() is always set to 1 no matter which item is currently in the loop

Comment: If you showed us your code then we could tell you where it's wrong. Don't be frightened or ashamed! It's part of the professional discipline of a good programmer to invite criticism of your work, and learn from it. That's the only way you will improve.

Comment: @Holden: note that I use a `<xsl:foreach>` element to iterate over the nodeset. (Note, you can use predicate expressions in the `match` attributes of your template, too.) But the crux is that `position()` depends on the position of the _current_ element within the _currently selected_ node set -- in my example all element childs. So if you have a control flow where your nodeset ends up with only one element in it, the position of this element within that nodeset will always be 1.

Comment: thank you, I partially solved my problem. In fact I was manipulating the itemstyle.xsl instead of the contentquerymain.xsl.